# iMac Crashes kernel Panic

Tags: mac, imac, crash, kernel-panic

I have an iMac, and always crashing almost everyday. Can you please point me out to the right direction? Below is the Report after it had crashed.
I Have already reverted to factory settings. no software installed, still the same. Upgraded or not to the lasest OS ,same issue.
Does anyone know what is the problem? I'm new to iMac, mercy. Thanks in Advance

```
*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801b720bae): "a freed zone element has been modified in zone ipc ports: expected 0xffffff8031e9f5a0 but found 0xffffff8031e9f580, bits changed 0x20, at offset 0 of 160 in element 0xffffff802f46b900, cookies 0x3f0011f8906d50c2 0x5352102bf3b1c29"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-3248.50.21/osf mk/kern/zalloc.c:503
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff9127333b50 : 0xffffff801b6dab12
0xffffff9127333bd0 : 0xffffff801b720bae
0xffffff9127333c40 : 0xffffff801b720656
0xffffff9127333c80 : 0xffffff801b71f2e2
0xffffff9127333db0 : 0xffffff801b6c784e
0xffffff9127333e20 : 0xffffff801b6c8ce3
0xffffff9127333e70 : 0xffffff801b6d463b
0xffffff9127333ec0 : 0xffffff801b6d1c84
0xffffff9127333f10 : 0xffffff801b7b8dca
0xffffff9127333fb0 : 0xffffff801b7ecc86

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: watchdogd

Mac OS ver



System Profile:
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x111), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.10
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430554738454655352D474E4C2D46
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314736453220
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
Model: iMac14,1, BootROM IM141.0118.B13, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.14f24
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Model: iMac14,1, BootROM IM141.0118.B13, 4 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.14f24
Graphics: Intel Iris Pro, Intel Iris Pro, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x45424A3430554738454655352D474E4C2D46
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x802C, 0x384B54463531323634485A2D314736453220
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x111), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
Bluetooth: Version 4.4.5f3 17904, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: APPLE HDD HTS541010A9E662, 1 TB
USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
Thunderbolt Bus: iMac, Apple Inc., 23.10
```

Comment: It seems you have not posted the whole panic Report. Did you install new Hardware? Does it happen when you unplug all devices? Also what is the Mac OS Version?

Answer (score 1):

It's a problem with the system files – try booting into Recovery Mode by restarting the computer and holding down `Command + R`.

After that, follow the steps to reinstall OS X. [This article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) might help you.